# The use of the function of matrix and pipe induce error for unused argument and dimnames in R

Tags: r, matrix, pipe, linear-regression, finance

```
> betas <- betas %>%
+   matrix(data= models, nrow = 5, ncol = num_factors +1, byrow = T, dimnames = list) %>%
+   data.frame(row.names = FAANG)%>%
+   colnames(betas) <- c("Constant", "Mkt_RF", "SMB", "HML", "RMW", "CMA")
Error in matrix(., data = models, nrow = 5, ncol = num_factors + 1, byrow = T,  : 
  unused argument (.)
```

when i type in this code, it kept showing me that the matrix(., got error of unused argument(.), while i did not put any symbol before data.

```
betas <- betas %>%
  matrix(unlist(models),nrow = num_factors, ncol = num_factors +1, byrow = T) %>%
  data.frame(row.names = FAANG)%>%
  colnames(betas) <- c("Constant", "Mkt_RF", "SMB", "HML", "RMW", "CMA")
```

```
Error in matrix(., unlist(models), nrow = num_factors, ncol = num_factors +  : 
  'dimnames' must be a list
```

this is the original code from the course of https://www.coursera.org/learn/using-r-for-regression-and-machine-learning-in-investment/lecture/Uq7v7/l5-understanding-machine-learning-concepts (free course), but it did not work as well.

Comment: The link only works if you are enrolled in the course. Try dput(betas) and dput(models) and paste the output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You pipe `betas` to `matrix()` but at the same time you provide all parameters to `matrix()`. Hence, there's no parameter that will use `betas` which is piped as `.` Piping puts your input as the first parameter. You can read more [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html).

In your second example, `unlist(models)` will be assigned to the `dimnames` parameter since it's the only parameter left.

Comment: You'll need something like `models %>% matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = num_factors +1, byrow = T, dimnames = list)`, assuming models is a vector and list is a list.